# Finding assets not in use

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

Is there a way to know what is of all my GO, textures, sounds, etc, are not in use in all scenes, to delete it?
When i tested my game, I have inserted some textures, sounds, GO etc and some of them are not in use.
I'm using Unity 5.1.1.

Comment: fortunately this is now easily solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Unity builds the executable, it does so only with required assets. Anything else that might exist in your scenes or projects is simply ignored.

[This answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/57909/find-unused-assets-in-project.html) over on Unity Answers has more info.

There are also options available in the Asset Store, such as [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22983).

> Asset Hunter is a tool that analyzes your buildlog and gives you an easily understandable overview over unused assets in your project folder.
>   The results are grouped into folders and file types, making it easy to start cleaning up your project.

Comment: The only exception are assets that are under a directory tree of [Resources](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) which are always included.

Answer (score 8):

## 2018 ..

## The modern solution is simply ..

[image]

Click on your scene(s) and select "Select Dependencies".

It will show you what is used; the rest is unused.  Really it's that easy.

---

As with many things in Unity pipeline, it is very common to use an asset,  virtually every project uses a few well known assets. "A+ Assets Explorer" ([link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/a-assets-explorer-57335)) is very common.

Comment: if we want to remove unused assets, how does a list of used assets take us beyond manual comparison of items in every asset folder?

Comment: EDIT: I take it back, this is pretty cool, because it highlights the used objects in every folder amongst other, unused assets. Further, you can select the dependencies of multiple scenes at one time.

Comment: Right, the fact is pretty much everyone has "A+ Assets Explorer"  :/ It's not perfect but it often helps